# Passing complex structures between java and c++

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I will work on project, that could be in the future relative complex java analysis tool. Java Swing is quite bad if you need custom components (the whole project will be a lot about nice user-friendly ui), so i want to use Qt5 and Qml. I still want to have the power of jvm, even because there is a lot work done in term of java libraries for instance for manipulation with java bytecode.

**Question:**
I will need to pass relative complex structures between java and c++. Walking through those complex java objects compositions in c++ with JNI will be probably very hard work, so i am thinking about building some protocol for communication through xml (on the java side, i will perform some actions and the result will be xml tree, which will be than just converted to string and passed to c++ application, which will convert it back to xml tree and work on that tree).

Is there any library or something which does this already or it is even good idea?

Comment: Perhaps something like [Google's Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) could be interesting in that context. It provides implementations for several languages.

Comment: FYI, the only tool that has a chance of making this task easier that I know of is [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) :)

Comment: Never tried it myself for this task, but at this time JSON seems to be standard and stable enough, and with wide support in most languages.

Comment: I am not aware of anything to simply the process.  Usually I create conversion functions that take C data structures or C++ objects and convert them to a Java object using JNI as you described.  Its a bit tedious in the beginning, but after you have a few of them setup is usually very strait forward.  Because you are wrapping a cross-platform library with a uniform API, you may want to look into something like JNA to avoid creating all of that boiler plate code.  It would allow access to your native functions from pure Java so you shouldn't have to worry about the conversion.